# Date picker in razor view with restriction

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Hello supposing i have a model with a field like this:
(mvc5)

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
```

In the razor view (3.0) i use the Html helper to show a date picker field, like this:

```
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.reunion.Date)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.reunion.Date)
```

On the input on the html i will have something like this:

```
<input class="text-box single-line valid" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date must be a date." data-val-required="O campo Date é necessário." id="reunion_Date" name="reunion.Date" type="date" value="2017-01-01" aria-required="true" aria-describedby="reunion_Date-error" aria-invalid="false">
```

And the image of the picker of date:

[image: Picker of date]

It works fine.

But let's suppose i want to restrict the date the user can select to only dates that are equal or more than the actual date.
What is the way i could do that?

Comment: Try to restrict by java-script function using maxDate and minDate

Comment: Why you are taking date as Nullable?

Comment: The date is Nullable date because generated the model from the database, where i left the option to allow nulls.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this -

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Date").datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: what is the issue coming with this solution?

Comment: check this - http://20fingers2brains.blogspot.com/2013/05/restrict-date-range-in-jquery.html

Comment: Hi, because i was using an input of type date, chrome by defect uses a date picker, that's different from the one of the jquery UI. I'm a little confusing with this because i'm new to html 5, asp.net mvc...

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom attribute, here I have an example:

```
public class FutureDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return value != null && (DateTime)value > DateTime.Now && (DateTime)value < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
    }
}
```

And in model is something like:

```
[FutureDateAtribute]
public DateTime mydateTime { get; set; }
```